# Can I paste my google analytic code in .css file which is included on every page

Tags: html, css, google-analytics

I have signed up for Google Analytics, and it gave me code to paste on every page I want to track, so can I paste it in my `.css` file as I have included that file in every webpage? So, may I expect that that google analytic code is included on my every webpage?

Comment: You have to put the Google Analytics code in the body of the HTML file to be execute it.

Comment: Maybe this is a typo and your question is about an external javascript file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your google analytic code would then be interpreted as CSS, and largely discarded by browsers. Anything that isn't will be read as CSS, and thus do Fun things.

You need to toss it into its own file (probably something `.js` assuming it's Javascript) and include that on every page- or if it's a widget (HTML rather than just JS), you'll have to insert the widget itself onto each page.

And uh... no offense but.... Honestly surprised I managed to give this one a straight-faced answer. CSS is non-executable. [Microsoft had js in it for a while (IE LTE 7 woo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't believe that's been something anyone has done since due to it being too large of an attack vector and extremely lagy.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to add Analytics tracking to your page, and placing the tracking code in your .css file is *not* one of them. The only thing that should be placed in a .css file is css.

You need to include the snippet Google provides in every page you'd like to track before the closing `</head>` tag. You can also use the [Google Tag Manager](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?rd=1).

This is what the official [Google Analytics website](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) says:

> Paste your snippet (unaltered, in its entirety) into every web page
>   you want to track. Paste it immediately before the closing 
>   tag. If you use templates to dynamically generate pages for your site
>   (like if you use PHP, ASP, or a similar technology), you can paste the
>   tracking code snippet into its own file, then include it in your page
>   header.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add javascript tracking code to a css file and expect it to be executed. Mixing js and css in a single css file is nothing a browser does (the closest were computed styles on Internet Explorer which had vaguely script-ish syntax). I still suspect you have meant to ask for an external javascript file, which would indeed work.

**You can, however, do Google Analytics tracking via a css file.**

For that you would construct a tracking url via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) and set it for example as a background image to an element if your page

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body { 
    background-image:url('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=555&dp=%2Fmy%2Fdocument%2Fpath');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In a similar way you could do event tracking etc, just add a class with a properly formed tracking url as background image when you want the event fired.

However this comes with a few caveats:

You would need to generate all parameters, including the [client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) yourself and pass them dynamically to the css.

If you were to use a CSS file, you'd need to generate it dynamically with some programming language on every pageview (plus you'd need to maintain the session yourself so you get same client ids on subsequent pageviews and visits).

Usually we strive to have the CSS file cached, so the user has to download it only once. That would not work here, or you would track only one pageview per visit.

I'm sure there are even more problems with this approach and while interesting in theory it is nothing something I would recommend. But in the spirit (if not the words) of the question I thought I#d mention it.

Comment: Interesting solution to implement Analytics with CSS only: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/10/css-only-solution-for-ui-tracking/

Answer (score 0):

No, css files are for css **only**.

**However**, a common approach is to create a new html file (often called default.html) with the code from Google Analytics and a link to your css. You can then include this file on every page instead of just linking to your css.